# OSGeo4W GDAL Polygonize Batch Convert?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, batch, polygonize, osgeo4w

I'm trying to use GDAL polygonize to run a batch convert but I cannot for the life of my figure out a way to get it to read a text file as input that contains all of the commands.

Do you know the correct command to run this conversion in one step so I don't have to do it many times over?

Here's an example of a single line of my input txt file:

```
gdal_polygonize X:\Source-Imagery\Satellite\WaterMask\Collection_5\2000\ALL\MOD44W_Water_2000_ML1920.tif\MOD44W_Water_2000_ML1920.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" X:\Source-Imagery\Satellite\WaterMask\Collection_5\2000\ALL\MOD44W_Water_2000_ML1920.tif\MOD44W_Water_2000_ML1920.shp
```

The txt file contains 176 lines to convert.

Answer (score 2):

It should work this way:

1. Start the OSGEO4W shell
2. Change the folder with `cd` to the folder where your batch file is, or copy the batch into the folder where the shell lands
3. Run the batch inside the shell by manually typing `filename.bat`

You don't need to care for PATH variables, this is done when starting the OSGEO4W shell.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:

1. Save text file as a ["batch file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) by changing the file extension from ".txt" to ".bat"
2. double-click that file and away you go.

Comment: I guess it's not that easy.  I get the error: "gdal_polygonize is not recognized as an internal or external compatible program or batch file".

Any other suggestions? There must be a way to force Windows to use OSGeo4W, right? Is there something I should change on my commands?

Comment: is OSGeo4W installed in `C:\OSGeo4W\bin`? You could try adding that to your PATH. Though check here for possible side effects: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/121. Prepending the full path to gdal_polygonize in your batch file might also work `C:\OSGEO4W\bin\gdal_polygonize` ...

Comment: Thanks for the tips but nothing has succeeded thus far. My OSGeo4W (GDAL Polygonize) is location here: 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin'. I've tried adding the paths but I still get errors and nothing is converted.  I've tried: 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal_polygonize X:\Source-Imagery\Satellite\....tif\MOD44W_Water_2000_KJ3334.tif -f "ESRI Shapefile" X:\Source-Imagery\Satellite\....tif\MOD44W_Water_2000_KJ3334.shp' I've also tried adding the .py and .bat

Comment: Did you try adding C:\OSGeo4W\bin to your windows PATH? Best reference I could find quickly: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml  This is java specific, but the general idea is the same

Answer (score 1):

I think this might solve your problem:

To set up the o4w environment, add this to the start of your bat file:

`Call C:\OSGeo4W\bin\o4w_env.bat`

Run all the lines from the text file there.